# Read data from USB using C++ on Windows 7

Tags: c++, windows-7, io, usb, libusb

I'm trying to read the output from a Trimble SPS-361 GPS receiver, which is connected to a Windows 7 machine via USB, using [C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++) (preferably) or [Java](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_%28programming_language%29). I know people have asked similar questions, but I can't seem to find what I'm looking for. It sounds like [libusb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libusb) is my best bet, is that true? If so, what is a good tutorial/guide/example code?

It sounds like I need to install/write some sort of device-specific driver and then I can read data off the device with C++ through libusb. Is that the general process for reading from a USB or am I confused?

To summarize what I think need (I know I'm all over the place):

1. An explanation/tutorial of how to communicate with USB's in general
2. A more specific tutorial/guide/example code of how to read data off a USB device on Windows 7
3. What exactly is libusb and is it what I am looking for?

Comment: Many USB GPS receivers act as if they're serial ports, precisely so they don't need a custom USB driver

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, if you want the raw data from the device, you can find it in the USB device list and literally read from it like a file.

Start with getting all the devices:

```
HDEVINFO hDevInfo = SetupDiGetClassDevs( &HIDWatch::GUID_DEVINTERFACE_HID, 0, 0, DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE );
```

Enumerate each one until you find what you're looking for:

```
SetupDiEnumInterfaceDevice( hDevInfo, NULL, &HIDWatch::GUID_DEVINTERFACE_HID, index++, &InterfaceInfoData )
```

Get the device detail via `SetupDiGetInterfaceDeviceDetail`... then open a file handle to the device path via `CreateFile` with `GENERIC_READ` access... run an `DeviceIoControl` to get the product string using `IOCTL_HID_GET_PRODUCT_STRING`.  If it's not your device, close up the file `CloseHandle`.  If it is yours, sit in a loop (preferably on a thread) doing a `ReadFile` and you'll get raw records from the device.

That should get you going...

Comment: +1 Thanks, this is really helpful. I'm guessing The HDEVINFO class and the two SetupDi* methods are from libusb Library?

Comment: The API is Microsoft's, check out [this link for docs on the first method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551069(v=vs.85).aspx).  Also, the example I showed is for "human interface devices"... if your device isn't presenting a HID interface you might need to expand your search into other device types.

Answer (score 0):

Normally a GPS sensor is exposed as a serial port in Windows. There is no need do specific USB handling.

Simply do serial communication via CreateFile/ReadFile and parse the received GPS NMEA data.